# Enviar um comando para o Terminal via C++

Tags: c++, linha-de-comando, terminal

Como fazer para enviar um código para o terminal?

***Por exemplo:*** em uma tela gráfica onde eu digito o nome de uma pasta, e ele envia para o terminal um `mkdir NomePasta` ? (Claro, serão outras funcionalidades, como executar programas por exemplo, mas só preciso saber como enviar o comando).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`system`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system). No entanto devo alertar que deve tomar muito cuidado com ele. Em primeiro lugar por que esse comando vai enviar o argumento diretamente ao terminal, que vai executar de acordo com o ambiente do usuário. Assim talvez o comando não faça o que você espera que ele faça. Se foi definido um *alias* para `mkdir`, ou se o próprio executável tiver mudado.

Outro problema é que com o argumento dado pelo usuário. Se ele disser que o nome da pasta é `documentos && rm -rf /`, você vai causar danos ao computador se executar o comando assim. É algo bem parecido com SQL Injection (pesquise).

A solução é fazer o que você quer fazer com o comando, sem usar o comando. Por exemplo, se quer criar um diretório, que tal usar a **função** [`mkdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) que é perfeitamente segura e faz exatamente o que a documentação diz que faz? Em suma: procure alternativas.

Comment: Oi Guilherme, tem razão sobre o injection, mas como será pra uso interno não deve haver problemas... Não vejo alternativas, dei o exemplo da pasta mas na verdade eu preciso chamar outros scripts passando o nome do arquivo como parâmetro (ou seja, dou um Browse com input no nome, e jogo com os comandos predefinidos pra automatizar o procedimento).

Answer (score 2):

Já faz um <strike>milênio</strike> tempo que não mexo com C / C++ mas acho que isso pode te ajudar.

```
#include <stdlib.h> 

    int main (int argc, char* argv[]) 
    { 
       system("mkdir NomePasta");
       return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma bem bacana de você fazer isso é assim sem precisar usar o comando system, você acessando o arquivo e executando no terminal retornará o resultado de tal comando.

`   FILE *arq;

```
char *command = (char *) "route -n";
  
char line [256];

  
if( !(arq = (FILE*)popen(command, "r"))) {
   
 cout << "falha";
   
 exit(1);
  } `
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).